# Update Phalcon model from POST values

Tags: php, phalcon

Is there a way in Phalcon to pass a posted form to a model and have it updates (or create) the models values?

Such as, if I have a model such as:

```
<?php
class User extends ModelBase
{
  public $id;
  public $first_name;
  public $last_name;
  public $email;
  public $username;
  public $password;
  public $active;
```

Is there a way to pass the posted array (providing the field names are the same) and have it update the model after calling `save()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
$user = Users::find(1);
$user->update($this->request->getPost());
// or
$user->update($this->request->getPost(), array('first_name', 'last_name'));
```

You can also use `$user->save()` to create/update model if needed. As far as I remember Phalcon will update or create user model depending if `primary_key` of that model exists in database.

More here: [request env](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/request.html#accessing-the-request-from-controllers) and [updating models](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#creating-updating-records).

Comment: Yeah?! That sounds awesome and will save so much time! I'm guessing if there are any transformations I want to do, I can update the Post variable through `setPost()` (i'm assuming that function exists`?). My only worry with this is that a user could technically copy the request, add in a field that is in the model (such as a password or access level field) and set this. Is there any way to prevent this, such as setting certain fields in the model through annotations or similar that can prevent update from a post?

Comment: Just read the documentation. It says you can set a whitelist field- would be good if you could set a blacklist array as well of fields!

Comment: I don't recall the blacklist for update not I didn't dig on annotations. I'm using manually `getPost('field',...)` to sanitize input. For updating the post vars you can make some var to store post and change values there (`$post = $this->getPost(); $post['foo'] = 'bar';$user->update($post));`).